# How to get all internal ids of one custom record

Tags: netsuite

I'm doing Netsuite integration with Java so I've created one custom record `test` and it has custom fileds x, y, z...

I entered some test records, and now I want to get all test records when I give Internal id of `test`.

Currently I'm passing internal ids of all records but I want by using main internal id(626) .

How to get all these internal ids(101, 202).

```
CustomRecordRef[] customRec = new CustomRecordRef[3];
String[] internalIds = {"101", "202"};

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    CustomRecordRef crr = new CustomRecordRef();
    customRec[i] = crr;
    crr.setTypeId("626");
    crr.setInternalId(internalIds[i]);
}
```

How do I get those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried CustomRecordSearch?  If you want them all then the only filter you should need to set is recType in the CustomRecordSearchBasic.  I believe you are saying your custom type 'test' has an internalId of 626 which is what you want to use for recType.internalId.

Answer (score 0):

Records in NetSuite contain a function called getAllFields - cust.getAllFields() - not sure if that will work as a method in java. Returns an array with all fields.